# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:49 cannot recognize input near '(' 'stock_status_id' ',' in statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

Hive version : Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.1

While executing the insert into statement, I am getting the below error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:49
>   cannot recognize input near '(' 'stock_status_id' ',' in statement

```
INSERT INTO table tgt_ebr_stores_physical_counts (stock_status_id,stk_no,description,avg_unit_cost,phy_cnt_date,issue_date,rcpt_date,adj_date,review_date,on_reqst_only_flag,row_bin,primary_flag,new_qty,cap_qty,user_code,description_1) SELECT EIM_STOCK.STOCK_STATUS_ID,EIM_STOCK.STK_NO,EIM_STOCK.DESCRIPTION,EIM_STOCK_COSTS.AVG_UNIT_COST,EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.PHY_CNT_DATE,EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.ISSUE_DATE,EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.RCPT_DATE,EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.ADJ_DATE,EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.REVIEW_DATE,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION.ON_REQST_ONLY_FLAG,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.ROW_BIN,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.PRIMARY_FLAG,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.NEW_QTY,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.CAP_QTY,TSW_CODES.USER_CODE,TSW_CODES.DESCRIPTION FROM AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.EIM_STOCK EIM_STOCK JOIN AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.EIM_STOCK_LOCATION EIM_STOCK_LOCATION ON EIM_STOCK.STK_NO=EIM_STOCK_LOCATION.STK_NO JOIN AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.TSW_CODES TSW_CODES ON EIM_STOCK.ISSUE_UOM_ID=TSW_CODES.CODE_ID JOIN AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES ON EIM_STOCK_LOCATION.STK_NO=EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.STK_NO AND EIM_STOCK_LOCATION.LOC_CODE=EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.LOC_CODE JOIN AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.EIM_STOCK_HISTORY EIM_STOCK_HISTORY ON EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.STK_NO=EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.STK_NO AND EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.LOC_CODE = EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.LOC_CODE JOIN AAA_ORCL_SLK_M003P.EIM_STOCK_COSTS EIM_STOCK_COSTS ON EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.LOC_CODE=EIM_STOCK_COSTS.LOC_CODE AND EIM_STOCK_HISTORY.STK_NO=EIM_STOCK_COSTS.STK_NO;
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "As of Hive 1.2.0 each INSERT INTO T can take a column list like INSERT
> INTO T (z, x, c1)."
>
> [LanguageManualDML-Synopsis.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Synopsis.1)

Hive 1.1 does not support column list.

You should insert all columns by their order in the destination table.

```
INSERT INTO table tgt_ebr_stores_physical_counts SELECT ...
```